# Legacy MySQL database mapping to a good .NET ORM for system migration

Tags: c#, .net, orm, migration, data-migration

This is quite a long one, but I'd very much appreciate your thoughts and suggestions.

We are busy rebuilding a legacy system which was written in PHP and MySQL and replacing its components with ASP.MVC in C# and SQL Server. The legacy architecture leaves *much* to be desired and there is a serious issue with spaghetti code, no referential integrity in the DB, unused code and database fields and just generally bad coding.

As much as I'd love to, we can't just rip out all of the old code and replace it. The company needs to stay functional during the development process, so we will need to build new functionality while using the old databases to ensure that their data is accurate at all times. The level of data accuracy isn't real-time, but if we had 2 systems, they would have to be in sync 100% of the time. The old system uses 6 different MySQL databases, all on the same server, running Linux. We will be running Windows 2008 R2 on the new server for the new system and we are planning to use the latest version of SQL Server.

The problem I'm having to solve is:  I need to somehow map all of these databases into a consolidated model that we can use through C# to develop the new system on. Once we have moved all the functionality over to C#, we need to port the data into a DB that matches our code model. This DB will be running on SQL Server.  I'm not too worried about the migration just yet; my current issue is finding an ORM tool that will allow me to map these 6 MySQL databases into a single, well planned out and designed model that we can use for the new development.

The new model might have additional fields that we would have to store in a new MySQL database until we port the data across at some stage, so the ORM should support easily building entities that span multiple tables and databases.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is it viable in terms of effort? Is there an ORM that can do all of this? and what other way is there to maintain operational capacity of the company whilst developing on the system actively?

I have looked at these ORM options:

- SubSonic (great, but I think too lightweight for what we are trying)
- Entity Framework (looks like I might be able to use this if I use very dirty models with tons of stored procedures for inserts, updates and deletes)
- NHibernate (the client does not want us to use this due to bad experiences in the past)
- LLBLGen (seems like it can do what we need it to, but long term support could be a concern with the client)

Anything else I should look at? Is there a different approach I could try?

Comment: Is there any reason why you cant just design the new database, migrate / create data for testing, and develop against the new databases? Then when you are ready to switch over, you can migrate all the content at once, and switch over to the new apps. This should be more straightforward than relying on an ORM to switch out the persistance layer at the last minute, and will allow you to develop against a well implemented clean model and database.

Comment: Hi @sga101, we need to add business value during the development process and we'd like to give the client new functionality and phase in the new user interface as we develop. We unfortunately can not finish up with development and switch over in one go, as the risk of bringing down operations is too high.

Answer (score 0):

ORMs aren't designed to solve the problem you have.  That said, a quality ORM will get you some percentage of the way toward a solution.

NHibernate is the easy choice.  LLBLGen would be my second choice.  I wouldn't even bother with EF or SubSonic as they are very feature poor compared to the other two and you need decent feature support in your scenario.

You'll likely have to invest a lot of time in writing custom code around your migration requirements.  Your use case is not a standard, well traveled path.

Answer (score 0):

For Entity Framework: if you're prepared to maintain one complete set of stored procedures with a static interface (i.e. same signature) you could implement them all in Transact-SQL on the SQL Server box, with linked servers (to the MySQL farm).

When the time comes, you could migrate the data into SQL Server and update your stored procedures.

Basically, design a nice model with nice stored procedures, and as a temporary solution implement any ugliness inside the stored procedures. Once MySQL is out of the way, you can replace the stored procedures with better ones.

SQL Server has a tendency to retrieve the entire remote table when you're running queries against a linked server, so if performance is a concern it might eventuate that all your stored procedures are wrappers around [`OPENROWSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) (see Example A for running a query on a remote server).